# What takes more space: Saving in DB or saving in a empty file?

Tags: android, file, database-performance, conceptual

I made an Android application to read cartoon strips from the Internet. It was a basic project to learn how to code for Android.

It saves very simple data in a DB:

```
Date (as string)|IsFavorite (as boolean)|Seen (as boolean)
```

When I first built the application, I used many reusable code from StackOverflow and from other Android forums. It's basically using a helper class to control DB access that is a singleton [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798233/concurrent-writing-to-android-database-from-multiply-services) and in many other places.

I'm not a fan of Singletons... and I started to wonder if using DB is really the best solution for such a simple amount of data written in the DB:

- There is no relationship information that I would need to cross between items inserted in the DB
- Checking if a strip was seen or not is a matter of checking if a file (empty) was created in the file-system (leave a empty file in the FS).
- There is no structure to be followed
- There is no need of scalability

So, here is my question:

1. If I leave an empty file in the FS instead of writing an entry in the DB, would it take more space in the FS?
2. If yes, would it be a negligible amount of space? Or would it cause a huge hit in the FS?

I'm talking here about 11000 files.

Comment: See it this way, a file with 1 character in would be seen as 4 096 bytes
a file with 1000 characters in would also be seen as 1024kb.
SO if you have 11000 files with less than 4 096 bytes of data in it will STILL be 11000 x 1024 kb. But a single file DB would have limited 'empty' or unused space. IMHO a database would be easier and smaller. So you will have to compare the Actual Size vs Size on Disk in both the DB and 11000 files.

Comment: You can't cleanup files scattered across the filesystem like you can for deleting records from a database. I don't see why not to use a database and if you don't like the singleton approach, then don't use it that way

Comment: @cricket_007 sure, I was planning to use DI+Executor to control DB access. The thing is, if I use a simple method to check if file is present or not, it would simplify to the extreme the application, right?

Comment: In terms of "time to access", I think "checkIfFileExist()" versus a query to the DB would take around the same amount of time (nearly none).

Answer (score 0):

Using a singleton in the database helper *is* the "Android way" of doing things, so there won't be any issues as far as that goes.

11,000 files that contain even a single character plus the other files & assets that make up the app itself will probably put you over the [100 MB file size limit](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469#apk).  Even if that isn't the case though, I think you are asking the wrong questions.  Rather than focusing on which takes less space, you should think about which is more *performant*.

The database will be perform ***significantly*** faster than using the filesystem.  Just a few reasons why...

1. CRUD operations can be performed in bulk rather than one at a time (*ie. update 100 entries all at once with a single query rather than one file at a time as you would with the filesystem*)
2. Each CRUD operation itself will take less time because it doesn't have to wait on the filesystem to open and close files.
3. There will be much less empty space reserved in the database than there will be for individually stored files, especially for the small amount of data you'd be storing in each file.
4. The database doesn't have to deal with fragmented files in the same way that the filesystem itself does.